# InstallAnywhere issue: This application has unexpectely quit

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, c#, odbc, dsn

I have downloaded IBM Client SDK 4.10 FC5DE for Windows x64. When I proceed to install it, InstallAnyWhere popups saying "Preparing installation files...". When it reaches to 100% below error is shown and installation terminates:

```
This application has unexpectely quit:
Invocation of this Java application has caused an InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit (LAX).
```

And If I click on details button its show stack trace:

```
ZeroGu6: Windows DLL failed to load
    at ZeroGa4.b(DashoA10*..)
    at ZeroGa4.b(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.b(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(DashoA10*..)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)
```

My OS is Windows 8.1 Pro and I have the last Java x86 and Java x86_64 installed on my system. Java x86_64 is the only activated in Java configuration panel. If I activated both, it does not work either. Leaving activating Java x86 it does not work either.

Below the Java packages installed on my system:

- Java 8 Update 151
- Java 8 Update 151 (64-bit)
- Java(TM) SE Development Kit 6 Update 24

So any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Yeah, you have Java installed! Kill it, kill it with fire!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.

In order to work you need to set Compatibility Mode to Windows 7 for setup ( executable file).

Right click on setup file, go to compatibility tab, and then set "Compatibility Mode" to "Windows 7". Also in configuration, you can check "Launch this program as Administrator".